# Table of proportions for multiple factors with various levels

Tags: r

I have a data set like the following:

```
source <- c("Email","Email","University","Google","Wordpress","Government","University","Email")
TLD <- c(".com",".com","net",".com",".edu",".com",".gov",".org")
speed <- c("1MB/s to 10MB/s","1MB/s to 10MB/s","1KB/s to 99KB/s","100KB/s to 1MB/s","1MB/s to 10MB/s","1MB/s to 10MB/s","10MB/s to 100MB/s","1MB/s to 10MB/s")
ping <- c(120,250,32,66,502,222,307,21)
install <- c("Yes","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes")
df <- data.frame(source,TLD,speed,ping,install)
```

I would like to make a prop table for all of the categorical variables at once if possible for a single table. Is there any way to do this?

My desired output would look something like this:

```
Factor          Level          N (%)
source          Email          5
                Google         10
                Wordpress      2
      ...      ....     ...
install         Yes            42
                No             58
```

Comment: Fixed, my apologies, was just listing the levels of the factors without thinking of the overall dataset.

Comment: Maybe something like `lapply(df, function(x) 100*proportions(table(x)))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving my problem.
Thanks for the help.

```
#Categorical data summary
prop.Fun <- function(x){
dfProp <- cbind(table(x, useNA="ifany"),round(prop.table(table(x, useNA="ifany"))*100, 2))
colnames(dfProp) <- c("Count", "Proportion (%)")
dfProp
}

lapply(df[,c(1,2,3,7,8,10,15)], prop.Fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the data in long format, `count` each occurrence of column and it's value and calculate the percentage.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = as.character)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  count(name, value, name = 'N') %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(N = prop.table(N) * 100)
```

Comment: Awesome. Perfect. Thank you Ronak!